# Display status reason for activity entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have several custom activities. 
I would like to list them in one view which I add to the activitypointer entity. 
This works great. 
Now, I would like to add the Status Reason (statuscode) to the view. That seems to be impossible. 
Is this conceptually possible?
Is the Status Reason of the different activity entities forwarded to the activitypointer entity at all?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box / Supported this is not possible. because CRM does not allow to change the activity system views to add the Status Reason attribute.

Unsupported this is possible: By adding a subgrid to your entity pointing to the Activitypointer entity. Then with some JavaScript & jQuery you can modify the layoutXML of the grid. Meaning you can add the statusreason attribute to the grid.

This can be done by using jQuery to get the subgrid Object and modifying the layoutxml Parameter (objSubGrid.control.SetParameter("layoutXml", LayoutXml);). A useful link can be found here  [CRM 2015 Filter a subgrid](http://mehmet.ozdemir.id.au/2015/03/crm-2015-filter-a-sub-grid-to-show-data-based-on-hierarchy-using-fetchxml/)